# Create MySQL user without password appearing in cleartext?

Tags: mysql, security, passwords

I'm curious if there's a way to create a password-protected user without allowing the password to appear literally in an expression or unmasked on the command line at any point during the process.

In the official MySQL documentation, it's mentioned that submitting passwords unmasked on the command line, such as when logging into an account, is considered insecure:

> Setting a password using mysqladmin should be considered insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines. MySQL clients typically overwrite the command-line password argument with zeros during their initialization sequence. However, there is still a brief interval during which the value is visible. Also, on some systems this overwriting strategy is ineffective and the password remains visible to ps. (SystemV Unix systems and perhaps others are subject to this problem.)[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)

> This is convenient but insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines. MySQL clients typically overwrite the command-line password argument with zeros during their initialization sequence. However, there is still a brief interval during which the value is visible. Also, on some systems this overwriting strategy is ineffective and the password remains visible to ps. (SystemV Unix systems and perhaps others are subject to this problem.)[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html)

> If your operating environment is set up to display your current command in the title bar of your terminal window, the password remains visible as long as the command is running, even if the command has scrolled out of view in the window content area. The * characters indicate where you enter your password. The password is not displayed as you enter it.
> It is more secure to enter your password this way than to specify it on the command line because it is not visible to other users. However, this method of entering a password is suitable only for programs that you run interactively. If you want to invoke a client from a script that runs noninteractively, there is no opportunity to enter the password from the keyboard. On some systems, you may even find that the first line of your script is read and interpreted (incorrectly) as your password.[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html)

It's possible to log into an account while keeping the password obscured using the encrypted [.mylogin.cnf](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.htmlhttps://) file created with the [MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.htmlhttps://), but the password still has to be submitted at some point before the user first logs in.

Comment: What does this question has to do with software development or programming?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the reputation points to move it.

Comment: You can always delete it here and ask it over there.

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I can think of is to create the user without a password in an expression, then use [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html) to set the password:

```txt
$ sudo mysql -e "CREATE USER <username>;"
$ mysqladmin -u <username> -p password
Enter password:          # don't enter anything here
New password:            # enter new password
Confirm new password:    # repeat new password
```

The second line might need some explaining, so here's how it works:

1. `mysqladmin -u <username>` lets you act on behalf of `<username>`
2. `-p` is used to submit the user's password, but it's left blank since the new user has none.
3. `password` is a command to set a password. It can be used as `password=<new_password>` or used without a value to trigger a masked password prompt.